# Экспорт в Excel под Linux

Tags: c#, excel, поиск-библиотек

Какую библиотеку лучше использовать для экспорта отчетов в Excel (без установки MS Office) ?

Сейчас у меня написан код на ClosedXML. Все работало. Но после перехода на линуксовый сервер в логи начала писаться ошибка о том, что библиотека не поддерживает эту платформу.

Comment: MS Office это Windows, пишите данные в CSV, Excel поддерживает

Comment: @aepot файл только собирается на бэкэ с линуксом и возвращается на клиент, где стоит Windows. Да и нужно еще отрисовать границы таблицы. CSV это позволяет ? Пока бегло погуглил - ответа не увидел

Comment: CSV не позволяет границы, там только данные, но эксель умеет и фильтры и границы при импорте рисовать с одного тыка мышкой для CSV

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/NPOI